# how to convert for loop into a do while loop

Tags: loops, for-loop, do-while

can i ask for a help. i need to use a do while loop instead of for loop. but right now,, im having diffulty on how am i going to convert this codes into do while loop. here is the code:

```
int main()
{
    int i, j, n;

    //Reads number of rows to be printed from user
    printf("Enter value of n : ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        for(j=i; j<=n; j++)
        {
            printf("*");
        }

        //Moves to the next line/row
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the difference in output? Try both cases, compare output and fix accordingly. Also, I assume your language is C?

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{


int i, j, n;

//Reads number of rows to be printed from user
printf("Enter value of n : ");
scanf("%d", &n);

i=1;
do
{
    j=i;
    do
    {
        printf("*");
        j++;


    }while(j<=n);
    printf("\n");
    i++;
}while(i<=n);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
int i, j, n;

//Reads number of rows to be printed from user
printf("Enter value of n : ");
scanf("%d", &n);

i=1; 
do
{
 j=i;
    do
    {
        printf("*");
        j++;
    }while(j<=n);

    //Moves to the next line/row
    printf("\n");
    i++;
}while(i<=n);

return 0;
}
```